# PDFMerger.php to merge PDF from Links

Tags: php, pdf, merge

I downloaded PDFMerger from http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/  and tried the example below which worked fine

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
    ->merge('browser', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');

    //REPLACE 'file' WITH 'browser', 'download', 'string', or 'file' for output options
    //You do not need to give a file path for browser, string, or download - just the name.
?>
```

But the above only works if file exist, it does not work if PDF is generated from a link. I want to do as shown below

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('https://www.test.com/blob/getfile.php?AppId=171&dt=doc1&Seq=1', 'all')
    ->addPDF('https://www.test.com/blob/getfile.php?AppId=171&dt=doc2&Seq=2', 'all')
    ->addPDF('https://www.test.com/blob/getfile.php?AppId=171&dt=doc3&Seq=3', 'all')
    ->merge('browser', 'TEST2.pdf');

    //REPLACE 'file' WITH 'browser', 'download', 'string', or 'file' for output options
    //You do not need to give a file path for browser, string, or download - just the name.
?>
```

You can download the working version from (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30709147/PDFMerger.zip)

I also tried reading some resources on this but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: can you share your working code here? I have the same use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that has issues with downloading via URL, if you know the exact location of the PDF and you don't need authentication you could get the PDF first:

```
<?php
    function download_remote_file($file_url, $save_to) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
        file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
    }

    download_remote_file('http://www.ncu.edu.tw/~ncu25352/Uploads/201312311030531151830864.pdf' , 'uploads/temp.pdf');
?>
```

If you have a `uploads folder` in the same directory and it's writable it will download the file and call it **temp.pdf**. Then all you have to do is run your PDF merge and it will do as you wanted.